# How to post process a war with maven?

Tags: maven, war

I am wondering a nice way of post processing a war produced with maven to add libs to it.

I have a war that is generated by maven. This war has many dependencies with scope provided because the application server is meant to provide them through shared libraries (don't blame me for shared libs...)

I am trying to change this behaviour and to have a standalone war. I'd like to find a way to generate a war that contains those additional jar.

I have tried with an assembly to add the jars and repack it but w/o any success. Mainly because I didn't find a way to add dependencies from maven within an assembly.

Any point, suggestions or anything else that could help ?

Comment: You can try to create a profile with dependencies in compile scope.

Comment: @AleksandrM I've tried but didn't get it working. Mainly because dynamic scope were not very well handled by maven when I was importing those pom in other projects

Comment: BTW, I got it working by overlaying the war. I have a war that contains only the libs I want to add and just ask maven to overlay the war with these one. Work's fine